# Can't get Angular 9 to do a http.post successfully

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api call in my ApiService file like this:

```
public signin(dataObj:any) {
    let dataObjString = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
    let httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
    };
    return this._httpClient.post(this._domain + '/auth/signin?sessionId='+this.getSessionId(), dataObjString, httpOptions).pipe(map(
        data => {
            return data;
        },
        error => {
            console.log('Error', error);
            return error;
        }
    ))
}
```

I'm passing a json object from my component like this:

```
this._apiService.signin({
    "username": $('#username').val(),
    "password": $('#password').val()
}).subscribe((response:any)=> {
    console.log('SIGNIN response', response);
});
```

When I test the API call from POSTMAN it works fine.

What's the trick with getting this to work in Angular 9?

Comment: What is the response you are getting or error?

Comment: you are not subscribing to the response you are using pipe to manipulate the response?

Comment: @Dalorzo I'm getting a cross-origin error on the client side:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://54.144.195.181:8080/auth/signin?sessionId=1eaf3ed7-904c-4e90-bc44-ff6d396efbcd' from origin 'http://50.19.165.18:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

A 404 server response. But when I run it in Postman, i totally get a normal 200. Is there some sort of request mutation that Angular does different thatn Postman?

Comment: To do a .subscribe() for the response do I need to remove the `return` on the front of the `this._httpClient` call?

Comment: Can you prefix this proxy to the url of get `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` and try once? I think that error should go.

Comment: Tried with the herokuapp.com domain and it gave me this: `zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/auth/signin?sessionId=1eaf3ed7-904c-4e90-bc44-ff6d396efbcd 404 (Invalid host)
...
core.js:6185 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Invalid host", url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/auth/signin?sessionId=1eaf3ed7-904c-4e90-bc44-ff6d396efbcd", ok: false, …}`

Comment: Oh, I tried it again with ONLY the domain (minus the rest of the URL) and I got a 200 response: `core.js:6185 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse 
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase`

Comment: Add cors headers server side, or setup a proxy if you cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is totally an issue of the browser requiring an PREFLIGHT Options request from the server, where Postman doesn't have a preflight request. That's why it was working fine in Postman but not on my server.

I fixed the issue by using the Express.js Cors module adding it to my express.js config file right after the `var app = express()` statement:

```
var cors = require('cors');
...
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```